# Can I expand the results of the product of independent vectors to the product of correlated vector in Random Matrix Theory?

Tags: random-matrices

Consider I have an $M\times 1$ vector $\boldsymbol x$ whose elements are i.i.d. random variables. Based on Theorem 3.4 in [1], as $M\to\infty$, we have :

$\boldsymbol{x}^H\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}\xrightarrow{a.s.}tr(\boldsymbol{A})$

Now, consider that I form another vector $\boldsymbol{y}=\boldsymbol{\theta}\boldsymbol{x}$. Can I conclude that as $M\to\infty$,

$\boldsymbol{y}^H\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{y}\xrightarrow{a.s.}tr(\boldsymbol{\theta A\theta})$

?

Thanks in advance.

[1] Couillet R, Debbah M. Random matrix methods for wireless communications. Cambridge University Press; 2011 Sep 29.

Comment: What is $M$ and how is it related to $x$?

Comment: I edited the question, M is the size of the vector. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: How does $A$ (an $M \times M$ matrix) vary with $M$?

Comment: The spectral norm of A is limited as $M\to\infty$ and it is independent of x.

Comment: But what does convergence to $\text{tr}(A)$ as $M\to \infty$ mean if $\text{tr}(A)$ depends on $M$? It's like saying $f(M)$ converges to $M^2$.

Comment: Well, in the description of the theorem, it is said that variance of the elements of x is 1/M, but generally, this is what it says, just bounded spectral norm and independence from x.